# Model is extracting wrong features

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to write a code to classify the news documents in 5 categories- politics, business, tech, sports and entertainment.

Model is extracting the below feature names, under category - business,
people, users, technology, said, use, internet, online, phone, mobile, using, digital, computer, net, information, many

and these names for category - tech
said, company, year, growth, market, us, economy, shares, firm, 2004, bank, business, oil, rise, however

For all other categories extracted feature names are right but for the business and tech feature names should be interchanged.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, precision_score, confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import itertools
import math
import re
# NLP library to get stop words for english
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from time import time

# for supervised learning
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

```
training_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
sample_df = pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv')
```

```
categories = training_df['label'].unique().tolist()
categories
```

['politics', 'business', 'tech', 'sport', 'entertainment']

```
# Clean up Duplicates
training_df = training_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['text'])
```

```
stopwords_en = set(stopwords.words('english'))
def clean_white_spaces(text):
    '''Clean all insignificant words, and punctuations'''
    # Remove new line and Carriage returns
    text = text.lower().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').strip()
    # Remove multiple spaces
    text = re.sub(' +', ' ', text)
    # Remove all numeric or special characters
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
    # Remove stop words
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)

    tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords_en]
    
    text = ' '.join(tokens)
    return text
```

```
training_df['text'] = training_df['text'].apply(clean_white_spaces)
training_df['New Length'] = training_df['text'].str.len()
```

```
lbl_encoder = LabelEncoder()
training_df['label_nm'] = lbl_encoder.fit_transform(training_df['label'])
```

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(training_df['text'], training_df['label_nm'], test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

```
t0 = time()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(encoding = 'utf-8',
                             ngram_range = (1,2),
                             stop_words= None,          
                             lowercase = False,         
                             max_df = 0.95,
                             min_df = 10,
                             norm = 'l2',
                             sublinear_tf = True)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train).toarray()
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))
```

```
# Try with parameter values given in sklean eample
random_state=1
n_components = 5
beta_loss="frobenius"
alpha_W=0.00005
alpha_H=0.00005
l1_ratio=1
t0 = time()
nmf = NMF(n_components = 5, random_state = 42, solver = "mu", beta_loss = "kullback-leibler", max_iter= 1000)
model = nmf.fit(X)
W = nmf.fit_transform(X)
```

```
def display_topics(model, feature_names, num_top_words, topic_names=None):
    '''Print topics and their corresponding words'''
    for ix, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print("Topic ", ix)
        print(", ".join([feature_names[i] \
             for i in topic.argsort()[:-num_top_words - 1:-1]]))
```

```
display_topics(nmf, vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), 15)
```

Topic  0
people, users, technology, said, use, internet, online, phone, mobile, using, digital, computer, net, information, many

Topic  1
game, win, said, play, england, cup, side, coach, match, first, players, team, back, injury, season

Topic  2
mr, said, would, party, election, government, labour, blair, minister, people, public, secretary, brown, leader, told

Topic  3
film, awards, show, best, films, award, star, actor, music, singer, years, director, tv, including, us

Topic  4
said, company, year, growth, market, us, economy, shares, firm, 2004, bank, business, oil, rise, however

*# Topic 0 -- business

*# Topic 1 -- sport

*# Topic 2 -- politics

*# Topic 3 -- entertainment

*# Topic 4 -- tech*

Comment: Can you give a small sample of your training data? Also, if this is unsupervised learning, why can't you add the text labels after the fact?

Comment: For sample data you can look at that link https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/learn-ai-bbc/data